# Template not accepting arguments in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I am learning C++ so please forgive me if this is a dumb question, but I have been at this for quite a while.

I am trying to partially sort a vector using insertion sort.

Here is the function:

```
template <typename T> // template, typename: pg 419
void insertion_sort (T *a, long int n) { 
  for (long int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    for (long int j = i; (j > 0) && (a[j] < a[j-1]); j--) {
      std::swap(a[j], a[j-1]);  // swap: pg 1294, 1297
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my code for merge function:

```
    template <typename T> void sort(vector<T> &a, vector<T> & aux, long int low, long int high) {
        long int size = high - low + 1;
        if (size < INSERTION_THRESHOLD) {
                insertion_sort(a[low], (long int) a.size() - low); 
        }
        else {
                if (high <= low) {
                        return;
                }
                long int mid  = low + (high - low)/2;
                sort(a, aux, low, mid);
                sort(a, aux, mid + 1, high);
                merge(a, aux, low , mid, high);
        }
}
```

Here are the errors I am getting when compiling:

```
    sort.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void sort(std::vector<T>&, std::vector<T>&, long int, long int) [with T = double]’:
    sort.cpp:147:82:   required from here
    sort.cpp:71:51: error: no matching function for call to ‘insertion_sort(__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<double> >::value_type&, long int)’
       insertion_sort(a[low], (long int) a.size() - low); 
                                                       ^
    sort.cpp:71:51: note: candidates are:
    In file included from sort.cpp:6:0:
    sort.hpp:11:28: note: template<class T> void insertion_sort(T*, long int)
     template <typename T> void insertion_sort (T *a, long int n)
```

;

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `insertion_sort(&a[low], ...);`

Comment: `a[low]` is a reference to the element. Your `insertion_sort` expects a pointer.

Comment: Besides, shouldn't the second parameter to `insertion_sort` be the `size` you computed from `high` and `low`?

Comment: @reima Thank you for catching that!

Comment: I have a question. In C a[n] would be a pointer right? So a[n] if a is a vector, that is a reference then?

Comment: `a[n]` is not a pointer in C. Both in C/C++, it is a *reference* (beside the fact that you can't have reference variable in C).